# Checking if raster extent overlaps AOI in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have have a directory that contains many of rasters. I also have a polygon shapefile with a single record that defines my area of interest (AOI). I would like to copy all rasters that fall within (or partially within) said AOI to a new directory)

Currently, my code is like this

```
#set up paths and get list of rasters
arcpy.env.workspace = r'\path\to\raster\dir'
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
AOI = r'\path\to\aoi.shp'

#get geometry of single polygon in shapefile
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(AOI,['SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: AOI_geom = row[0]

for raster in rasters:
    raster_extent = arcpy.Describe(raster).extent
    if raster_extent.overlaps(AOI_geom):
        #copy raster to new dir....
```

However, the extent.overlap() always returns false, even when I can see visually that there is an overlap

Comment: Are the spatial references for both set correctly? Are they both the same? Is AOI_Geom in scope for the raster loop?

Comment: Doh! The spatial references were not the same, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was simply that the spatial references were not the same. Thanks Michael Stimson